# Cancan nested_routes restrict acces to :index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have some problems with cancan and a nested routes.

I have this routes :

```
resources :companies do
   resources :projects
end
```

I have no problem with the abilities for Company model but for the Project model I want to deny the access to Project#index if they are not admin of the company.

The next code works :

```
can :show, Company do |company|
   if user.admins.include?(company) #check if the user is admin of the company
      can :index, Schedule, :company_id => company.id
   end
end
```

But how I can do :

```
can? :index, Project
```

I tried by renamed the method like that :

```
can :index_projects, Company do |company|
   if user.admins.include?(company) #check if the user is admin of the company
      can :index, Schedule, :company_id => company.id
   end
end
```

and use :

```
can? :index_projects, @company
```

But it doesn't work. Do you know how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use something like this in your ProjectsController:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    authorize! :index, Ability
    @projects = Project.order(:created_at)
  end
end
```

and when you`ll try to access Projects#index CanCan will check abilities and deny or allow access according to user abilities

prooflink https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/209#issuecomment-609043

hope this is what you need =]

Comment: this is not work for me
Can you explain me step for this?

Comment: @ashvin follow the link I posted above (https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/209#issuecomment-609043)