# Cancan nested resources restricting access to index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I am currently using cancan in my web app and so far it works greats but there is a problem I am having regarding nested resources in rails. When accessing the index page cancan does not restrict a user from seeing what another logged in user can see. It works fine for the show pages but when visiting the index page it does not work.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :skater do
  resources :videos
end
```

**ability.rb**

```
can :manage, Video, :skater => { :user_id => user.id }
```

**video_controller.rb**

```
load_and_authorize_resource :skater
load_and_authorize_resource :video, :through => :current_user
```

How can I restrict access to another users index view so that user A cant view user B videos?

Comment: It doesn't look like you are in a nested resource. Could you please include the other `load_and_authorize_resource` calls you are using.

Comment: @BaylorRae' I have updated the above but did not have an effect

Comment: @BaylorRae' I've added `cannot [:read, :show], Video` and it worked but when I try to view my own video it does not work I received the same error as a restricted user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `:through => :current_user` to see if that fixed your problem. Look at the [second code example](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources) in the CanCan Wiki to see how nested resources are supposed to be used.

CanCan will grab the current user through a `current_user` method in your application. Because of this you don't have to define it when you are [authorizing controller actions](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions).

---

**Update:** Try using this in your controller.

```
load_and_authorize_resource :skater
load_and_authorize_resource :video, :through => :skater
```

---

**Update 2:** I can't tell if CanCan is failing because of [Ability Precedence](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ability-Precedence) or because the current user is simply unauthorized.

Based on what I've seen so far this is how your `ability.rb` file should look. The second line will overwrite the first line allowing you to limit how much can be viewed and changed. I decided to use `:manage` because it "covers all the bases" by including all the permissions.

```
cannot :manage, Video # this will include :read, :show, :edit, :update, and :delete
can :manage, Video, :skater => { :user_id => user.id }
```

A concern of mine is that you are not filtering the skater correctly. If you have any problems I would suggest trying this.

```
can :manage, Video, :user_id => user.id
```

Comment: I removed current_user and have added just :through => :skater and still nothing. Do you think the problem lies in my ability.rb file?

Comment: @coletrain I update my answer. See if that gets you any closer.

Comment: figured it out! I add if user and everything started working. I have updated your answer above a bit, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this question, it's the same problem as you.

[Cancan nested_routes restrict acces to :index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371781/cancan-nested-routes-restrict-acces-to-index)

Comment: This isn't quite the same problem. You're problem was because you didn't authorize the resource. @coltrain's problem looks to be because he is using `:through => :current_user`.